# how can i sort table data in descending order if my query run on a specific condition

Tags: sql

my table has employee promotion data. I want to find the last promotion of an employee. My query works properly when an employee has multiple promotion record, but if any employee has a single promotion record , query didn't work for single emp. data record

```
declare @lastProdate date
set @lastProdate=(
    select top 1  EffectDate 
    from fl_admpromotiondetails pro  
    where ActionType=1 
    and pro.EmpID=@EmpId  
    order by TraceNo desc
)
```

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: And add a tag for the dbms you're using. (Perhaps <sql-server>?)

Comment: That's non-standard SQL. Please tell us which database product you are using (looks like SQL Server as jarlh commented)

Comment: Nothing in this query would not work if there were on record in the table.  Can you set up a db fiddle of some sort to illustrate the problem?  Sample data and desired results *as text tables* in the question would help.